# Model server container out of memory - Vertex AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am trying to deploy a simple support vector regression (SVR) model to Vertex AI using scikit-learn version 1.0, but I am encountering the following error:

```
Failed to create endpoint "adpool_eval" due to the error: model server container out of memory,
please use a larger machine type for model deployment: 
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/configure-compute#machine-types.
```

The model is saved as "model.joblib" in a cloud storage bucket as required by Vertex AI.

The model is very small and simple so I can't understand how it is running out of memory. I tried machines with much more RAM and CPUs and the issue still persists. The cloud storage bucket, model registry, and endpoint are all in the same region (europe-west1).

Comment: Which container and machine type are you using?

Comment: I'm using this contrainer "europe-docker.pkg.dev/vertex-ai/prediction/sklearn-cpu.1-0:latest" and I tried multiples types of machines n1, n2, e1, e2-highmem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be with saving the model using the joblib library. I used the pickle library instead and I managed to deploy the same model without any issues on the n1-standard machine.